# Add unicode character to document

Tags: unicode, newunicodechar

I'm trying to enter two Unicode characters in my document. 
The first is [「](https://unicode-table.com/en/14A5/) and the second is [」](https://unicode-table.com/en/14A7/). However, none of the solutions I've seen thus far have been able to help me implement these two characters. The following code is where I try to insert the characters using the methods mentioned in other posts like

```
\newunicodechar{}{}
```

or

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{}{}
```

or

```
\char"
```

I am not entirely sure if I have used these commands correctly that's why I have provided the entirety of my code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{「}{\mopen}
\newunicodechar{」}{\mclose}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{14A5}{\mopen2}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{14A7}{\mclose2}

\title{Unicode char test}
\author{Skip}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\mopen「test\mclose」
\char"14A5

\end{document}
```

In this document I'm trying to print "[「](https://unicode-table.com/en/14A5/)test[」](https://unicode-table.com/en/14A7/)" and below that just the character "[「](https://unicode-table.com/en/14A5/)". 
In the output, I just get "Test" and for some reason, it prints "14A52 14A72" on the preceding page. The output is accompanied by a few undefined control sequence errors relating to the use of

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{}{}
```

and

```
\mopen 
\mclose
```

For further information; I am using XeLaTeX on Sharelatex.

I hope the information provided will be sufficient to answer my question.

Comment: if you are using xelatex then do not use `inputenc`

Comment: have you seen `\mopen` defined anywhere? it is not a command name that I recognise.

Comment: you could use `\lceil` and/or `\rfloor` from `amsmath` package. (table 92 in The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List)

Comment: @naphaneal they are defined in the format, no package needed.

Comment: The character U+14A5 is CANADIAN SYLLABICS MI, probably not what you're looking for. The characters you're using are U+300C LEFT CORNER BRACKET and U+300D RIGHT CORNER BRACKET, available with `amssymb` as `\ulcorner` and `\lrcorner`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{「}{\ensuremath\lceil}
\newunicodechar{」}{\ensuremath\rfloor}
\title{Unicode char test}

\author{Skip}
\date{}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}


「test」


\end{document}
```

Comment: I used Times for the example image, just to demonstrate xelatex, but that is commented out as not needed for the answer.

Comment: Your example, with `\setmainfont`, would also work in LuaLaTeX, yes?

Comment: @RobtAll yes...